# AWS K8s Cluster Autoscaler with multiple node groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, autoscaling

Our user case is like this.
K8s cluster needs three autoscaling groups.

- ASG Group1 should create only on-demand AWS worker nodes with taint = "main_apps"
- ASG Group2 should create on-demand instances with taint = "jobs"
- ASG Group3 should create spot instances with taint = "jobs" i.e. same taint as Group2

cluster-autoscaler-priority-expander is set with Group2 priority as 10 and Group3 Priority as 20. Priority for Group1 is not specified.

With this configuration can we expect following behavior from ClusterAutoScaler with --nodes set to Group1, Group2 and Group3?

- When a pod is deployed with toleration = "main_apps", node from Group1 will be created
- When a pod is deployed with toleration = "jobs" then either node from Group3 or Group2 will be created honoring the priority